# Split a list Python

Tags: python, list, split

Hello I have a list containing one string that I need to split in two on the comma:

```
value = ['Red, Orange']
```

I split using :

```
value = value[0].split(", ")
```

But I get :

```
value[0] = "Red"
```

and

```
value[1:] = ["Orange"]
```

why is `value[1:]` a list? What can I do to get

```
value[1:] = "Orange"
```

Thanks

Comment: Because slicing will return a list, use indexing.

Comment: What made you use a ":" for the second one but not the first?

Comment: See here for info on slicing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/pythons-slice-notation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply do:

```
value[1]
```

without the `:`. This indicates to python that you are getting an element at a specific index and not a portion of the string from index 1 to the last element.

`value[0]` will contain `"Red"`

and

`value[1]` will contain `"Orange"`

What you are doing with the `[:]` is known as list slicing. Perhaps you should read about it so that it is clear.

Comment: thanks but value[1] gives me the error : `list index out of range`

Comment: @salamey, Well. After you do the split.

Answer (score -1):

You may write this:

value = [x for x in value[0].split(", ")]

It's called list comprehension and it will work for arbitrary number of words in value[0]

Comment: -1, a comprehension is totally unnecessary since split already gives a list. Also this doesn't answer the question